# "elaborated type refers to typedef" error when trying to befriend a typedef

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

Let's say I have the following piece of code (a simple CRTP class hierarchy). I want to typedef the base class type to save myself typing (in my actual code, I use the base class type more than once and the base class takes several template parameters), and I need to befriend the base class since I want to keep the implementation private.

```
template< class D >
class Base
{

public:

    void foo() { *static_cast< D * >(this)->foo_i(); }

};

template< class T >
class Derived : public Base< Derived< T > >
{

public:

    typedef class Base< Derived< T > > BaseType;

private:

    // This here is the offending line 
    friend class BaseType;

    void foo_i() { std::cout << "foo\n"; }

};

Derived< int > crash_dummy;
```

clang says:

```
[...]/main.cpp:38:22: error: elaborated type refers to a typedef
    friend class BaseType;
             ^
[...]/main.cpp:33:44: note: declared here
    typedef class Base< Derived< T > > BaseType;
```

How do I fix this? I noticed that I could simply type out the whole thing just for the friend class declaration and it works fine, but even a tiny bit of duplicated code makes me feel a tad uncomfortable, so I'm looking for a more elegant "proper" solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe that this is not possible with C++03, but was [added to C++11](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1791.pdf) in which you can simply omit the `class` keyword:

```
friend BaseType;
```

Comment: I am getting the same error on a line that doesn't use friend but a static enum..:

`static enum CGLineCap fl_quartz_line_cap_ = kCGLineCapButt;`

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Enable C++11 only and use `friend BaseType`

You cannot use friend class on typedef in C++03.

> An elaborated-type-specifier shall be used in a friend declaration for
>   a class(101)
>
> 101) The class-key of the elaborated-type-specifier is required.

```
elaborated-type-specifier:

class-key ::opt nested-name-specifieropt identifier

class-key ::opt nested-name-specifieropt templateopt template-id

enum ::opt nested-name-specifieropt identifier

typename ::opt nested-name-specifier identifier

typename ::opt nested-name-specifier templateopt template-id
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually can do it in C++ earlier than C++11, but it requires a fairly elaborate (haha) workaround, along the lines of, 1st declare this "helper":

```
template< class T > struct ParamTypeStruct { typedef T ParamType; };
```

Then, your friend declaration:

```
friend class ParamTypeStruct< BaseType >::ParamType;
```