# Declaring friend class template via wrapper

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, friend

I've seen the following pre-C++11 code, used as a trick to declare class template friends (which in C++11 can simply be done with `friend T;`)

```
template <typename T>
struct Wrapper
{
    typedef T type;
};

template <typename T> 
class Foo
{
    friend class Wrapper<T>::type; // effectively makes T a friend
};

struct Test{};

int main()
{
    Foo<Test> foo;
}
```

The code compiles fine on g++ (4.9/5.1/6), but fails under clang++ (3.5/3.6/3.7) with the error

> error: elaborated type refers to a typedef
>
> friend class Wrapper::type;

Is the code above standard compliant, i.e. valid or not?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21952658/type-dependent-nested-name-specifier-in-elaborated-type-specifier

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14623338/elaborated-type-refers-to-typedef-error-when-trying-to-befriend-a-typedef

Answer (score 1, accepted):

§7.1.6.3/2:

> **If the identifier resolves to a *typedef-name*** or the
>   *simple-template-id* resolves to an alias template specialization, **the *elaborated-type-specifier* is ill-formed**.

Answer (score 0):

It's not compliant. The grammar rules for `friend` in [class.friend]/3 are:

> A friend declaration that does not declare a function shall have one of the following forms:
>
> ```
> friend elaborated-type-specifier ;
> friend simple-type-specifier ;
> friend typename-specifier ;
> ```

`class Wrapper<T>::type` is none of those specifier types. It's not an *elaborated-type-specifier* because `Wrapper<T>::type` isn't an *identifier* or a *class-name*, and obviously isn't one of the other two either. What you're looking for is simply:

```
friend typename Wrapper<T>::type;
```

Comment: `friend class-key nested-name-specifier identifier ;` is allowed by 7.1.6.3

Comment: @Columbo So if `Wrapper<T>::type` was some actual type, rather than an alias, you could do `friend class Wrapper<T>::type`? Why allow a type but not an alias?

Comment: Yes, that is valid. Not sure about the second part, but I'll look for a DR.

Answer (score 0):

[dcl.typedef]/p8:

> [ Note: A *typedef-name* that names a class type, or a cv-qualified version thereof, is also a *class-name* (9.1)
>
> **If a *typedef-name* is used to identify the subject of an *elaborated-type-specifier*** (7.1.6.3), a class definition
>   (Clause 9), a constructor declaration (12.1), or a destructor declaration (12.4), **the program is ill-formed**.
>   — *end note* ] [*Example*:
>
> ```
> struct S {
>     S();
>    ~S();
> };
>
> typedef struct S T;
> S a = T(); // OK
> struct T * p; // error
> ```
>
> — *end example* ]

The code should fail at template instantiation time, which it does so correctly in Clang.

Using `typename` in place of `struct` allows the code to pass in both compilers.

Comment: Well, that's a note; Not normative.