# Is it possible to mark an alias template as a friend?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, friend, template-aliases

Imagine we have this code:

```
template <class, class>
class Element
{};

template <class T>
class Util
{
public:
   template <class U>
   using BeFriend = Element<T, U>;
};
```

Is it possible to mark `BeFriend` as a friend ? (Of `Util`, or any other class).

### Edit

The "obvious" syntax were tried, but both failed with Clang 3.6.

```
template <class> friend class BeFriend;
template <class> friend BeFriend;
```

I did not know about the second syntax, but [found it in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14623763/1027706). It seems to work (and be required) for **non**-template aliases, but does not help in this case where the alias is templated.

(*Note*: as some could infer from the minimal example, I am looking for a way to work-around the limitation that C++ does not allow to friend a partial template specialization)

Comment: try it (spoiler alert: you can)

Comment: @bolov: With which syntax ? I tried both `template <class> friend class BeFriend` and `template <class> friend BeFriend` with no success on Clang 3.6, so a little more details would go a long way here :)

Comment: I spoke too soon. I thought it was trivial. My bad.

Comment: @bolov Okay no problem ! I like the fact that people are upvoting your comment based on the fact it is very assertive, even though they probably do not appreciate the problem at hand ;)

Comment: I need to watch that movie again. The spoiler wasn't there :)). Tried like 10 combinations, nothing works.

Comment: @bolov Haha ;) I am afraid this movie does not have a happy-ending, but let's use this question to make sure.

Comment: If there is a way to do it, the committee doesn't know about it. See the note at the bottom of [CWG 1554](http://wg21.link/CWG1554).

Comment: @T.C.: thank you, that could probably be the (sad) answer to this question.

Comment: The sad answer is the answer, as far as I can tell - there's clear (enough) wording about what can be a friend in the relevant clause in the Standard and alias templates aren't in there, so that looks like a dead end. However, there could be a workaround for your underlying question (simulating a partial specialization friend), if you're willing to change the way `Element` is defined - it would involve nested class templates. Not sure if it would help you. It looks [like this](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/l2wQiOwLSEmL61uj).

Answer (score 9):

I think you can't do that because partial specializations could not be declared as friend.

From the stardard, [[temp.friend]/7](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.friend#7)

> Friend declarations shall not declare partial specializations. [
>   Example:
>
> ```
> template<class T> class A { };
> class X {
>   template<class T> friend class A<T*>; // error
> };
> ```
>
> —end example ]

You have to specify a more generic version such as:

```
template <class, class> friend class Element;
```

or a full specified version, such as:

```
using BeFriend = Element<T, int>;
friend BeFriend;
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not the alias, the problem is that
*"partial specialization cannot be declared as a friend"*.

```
template <class, class> friend class Element;        // OK

template <class, class> friend class Element<T, T>;  // Error
```