# Friend alias template does not compile with clang

Tags: c++11, gcc, friend, clang++, partial-specialization

The code bellow compiles without a warning on GCC and issues an error with clang (any c++11 compatible versions of both clang and GCC).
Which compiler is right with respect to the standard?
Specifically, is it allowed to declare as friend a non partially specialized template alias which is a partial template specialization of a class?

This makes me think that it might not be allowed:

1. cppreference says: "**Friend declarations cannot refer to partial specializations** [...]".
2. And also: "A type alias declaration introduces a name which can be used as a synonym for the type denoted by type-id. **It does not introduce a new type** [...]".
3. Finally: "Both **function template and class template declarations** may appear with the friend specifier [...]". It implicitly excludes the possibility for a template alias to be a friend of a class as an actual template alias but rather as the aliased class template, which is a partial specialization in the snippet bellow.

However, this makes me think that it might be allowed:

1. cppreference says : "**An alias template is a template** [...]". I undestand that a template alias is a distinct template. By consequence, declaring it as friend as in the following example without partial specilization of the class template alias is valid... Or not.
2. [This code](https://wandbox.org/permlink/l2wQiOwLSEmL61uj) (not from me) also gives a workaround and let me think that there is no obvious reason for making the following code ill-formed.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33563427/is-it-possible-to-mark-an-alias-template-as-a-friend) asks a very similar question but no clear answer was provided with respect to the specific usage of an intermediate template alias.

```cpp
template<typename T,typename N> class B{};

template<typename T> class A{
    // template<typename U> friend class B<T,U>; fails as expected
    template<typename N> using alias = B<T,N>;
    template<typename N> friend class alias;
};
```

Intent: legal way to declare a partial specialization as friend using an intermediate alias (workaround).

Result: GCC is happy with it and produces the intended behaviour. Clang produces the following error:

```
<source>:7:35: error: redefinition of 'alias' as different kind of symbol

template<typename N> friend class alias;
                                  ^
<source>:6:22: note: previous definition is here

template<typename N> using alias = B<T,N>;
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44213761

Comment: @chtz: So this seems to be a duplicate to the linked post? And this is not possible?

Comment: Edited my question to give some extra thoughts and clarify the question.